# Matrix norm of a permuted matrix

Tags: matrices

I have to prove that the norm of a matrix doesn't depend of the rows order.

If P is a permutation matrix, I have to show that 
$$||PA||_p=||A||_p$$

$x\neq0$

$||PA||_p= \frac{||PAx||_p}{||x||_p} $

$||PA||_p \leqslant \frac{||P||_p  ||Ax||_p}{||x||_p} $

$||PA||_p \leqslant \frac{1*  ||Ax||_p}{||x||_p} $

$||PA||_p \leqslant ||A||_p $

How can I get the equality ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply your same argument to the permutation matrix $P^{-1}$ to show $$\|A\|_p = \|P^{-1} P A\|_p \le \|PA \|_p.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easier way, in my opinion.

Trivially, $\Vert x\Vert_p=\Vert Px\Vert_p$ for any vector $x$ ($P$ just permutes the elements of $x$). Then, $$\Vert A \Vert_p=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert_p=1} \Vert Ax\Vert_p=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert_p=1} \Vert P(Ax)\Vert_p=\sup_{\Vert x\Vert_p=1} \Vert (PA)x\Vert_p=\Vert PA \Vert_p.$$